# Required ‘lang’ parameter is empty when making guzzle GET request to api.ai

Tags: php, get, request, dialogflow-es, guzzle

I am sending a GET request to api.ai through guzzle but getting this response:

```
     { "id": "83a493c7-386f-4e0a-93f8-6e3647f0f1be", "timestamp": "2017-07-29T19:40:22.172Z", "lang": "en", "status": { "code": 400, "errorType": "bad_request", "errorDetails": "Required 'lang' parameter is empty." } }
```

Below is my code:

```
try {  
 $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.api.ai/v1/query?
query=weather&amp;lang=\"en\"');        
}
catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
$response = $e->getResponse();
$responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();
echo $responseBodyAsString;
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile,  \GuzzleHttp\json_encode($e->getResponse('Status'),true));
fclose($myfile); die();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was url encoding error. I solved it by removing "amp;" from the url.